# How to get rid of background when something is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I am new to responsive design and am wondering how can I make the background colour disappear when SPAN is clicked on, my code is below:

**HTML CODE**

```
    <body>


    <span class="menu-trigger">MENU </span>


   <nav class = "nav-main">

            <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href = "#" class = "nav-item"> HOME</a>                              
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a href = "#" class = "nav-item">ABOUT US </a>
                </li>

                 <li>
                   <a href = "#" class = "nav-item">PORTFOLIO </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                   <a href = "#" class = "nav-item">SERVICES </a>
                </li>
                  <li>
                   <a href = "#" class = "nav-item">CONTACT US </a>
                </li>

          </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){

  .menu-trigger{
   display:block;   
      color:#305782;
      background-color: #d5dce4;
      padding:10px;
      text-align: right;
      font-size: 83%;
      cursor: pointer;
  } 

.nav-main {
     display:none;  
}

.nav-expanded{
   display:block;  
   background-color:none;

}
  .nav-main > ul > li{
      float:none;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #d5dce4;
      background-color:black;
  }

    .nav-main > ul > li:last-child{

      border-bottom: none;

  }

    .nav-main .logo{
  display:none;
}

    .nav-item:hover {

    background-color:forestgreen;

}
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
     <script type ="text/javascript">
        jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
   jQuery(".menu-trigger").click(function(){
        jQuery(".nav-main").slideToggle(400, function (){
          jQuery(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded").css('display', '');
        });

    });
});

    </script>
```

**JS FIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/k4ytvyef/2/
As you will notice when sizing the screen in mobile view the HOME option has a long background how can I get rid of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this under your jQuery code should do the trick.

```
window.onresize = function() {
  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 480px)').matches) {
    jQuery(".nav-main").css("background-color", "inherit");
  } else
    jQuery(".nav-main").css("background-color", "");
    jQuery(".nav-main").css("display", ""); // Display navbar back when you change width 
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer:) but what do you mean underneath my JQuery code?

Comment: And addressing your 'navbar gone' problem when you go back to full width. https://jsfiddle.net/k4ytvyef/7/

Comment: Hi, sorry again but something very weird happens when you change the css colour of the menu.trigger why does this happen?

Comment: Yes, it's because when you load the page window.onrezise doesn't trigger.

Comment: Never mind my css was just messing up , working now thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

When you say "get rid of background color", do you mean changing it to white? In that case, consider the below example call.

```
 $('yourIdOrClass').css({'background-color':'white'});
```

Comment: use none instead of white, wherever applicable

Comment: Hi I tried that and it does change the colour when expanding in mobile size but the problem is when I go back to normal size scrren i.e. desktop the nav bar is completely gone.